# Accessing node.js running on local computer

Tags: node.js, webserver

I'm running a node.js server on a Mac and want to share the URL with someone else.

When I access my public IP on the correct port, this doesn't work.

Is there another way to set it up to make it publicly accessible?'

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to forward the port in your router.

Comment: Also check the firewall settings in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy

Comment: Can you share the code you are using, so we can see how are you managing the config? Where are you listening?

Comment: When you start you local node.js server, try configure the node.js server to listen to 0.0.0.0/port

Answer (score 0):

Try `<Your Mac's IP>:<node server's Port>` on a different computer locally. You could also use `<Your external IP>:<node server's Port>` but you'll be needing to port forward the port in your router.